# Object Property returns NaN, then make object function fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing Javascript and tried to code an object that, when referenced in the webpage, will monitor user and log him out if he is inactive.

however, the object does not work as intended. I tried viewing the property `minsBeforeForceLogout` and it returns `NaN`

I tried setting the property to 0 before setTimeout because I have read that at the point of declaration the object does not have values yet, but still it does not increment.. how can I resolve this? I am using a mix of Javascript and Jquery

**EDIT**
I have got the NaN problem solved, but when I run the logout event does not fire on my if. Was there something wrong with my condition?

**EDIT 2**
I have replaced `setTimeOut` with `setInterval`

```
$(document).ready(function () {


/*below object mainly checks if user is inactive*/
var monitorIfActive = {
    minsBeforeForceLogOut : 0, //if this variable reaches threshold, logout commences
    threshold: 5,

    resetInactivity : function(e) {
        monitorIfActive.minsBeforeForceLogOut = 0;           
    },

    userIsInactive : function() {
        monitorIfActive.minsBeforeForceLogout++;
        swal(monitorIfActive.minsBeforeForceLogout.toString());// <- **returns NaN**

        if (monitorIfActive.minsBeforeForceLogout >= monitorIfActive.threshold) 
        {
            monitorIfActive.logout();
        }

    },

    logout: function () {
        swal("You have been logged out due to inactivity");
    }


}

//bind to html
$('body').on('keypress click mousemove scroll', monitorIfActive.resetInactivity);


//start the timer countdown for our monitor object.
monitorIfActive.minsBeforeForceLogOut = 0; //<- I tried this, but still it does not work.
var startMonitoring = setTimeout(monitorIfActive.userIsInactive, 1000); });
```

To clarify, I am trying to get to function logout, meaning the page will say "**You have been logged out due to inactivity**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition you have `minsBeforeForceLogOut` while in a bunch of other places you have `minsBeforeForceLogout` -- different camelcasing.

Comment: Thanks, that has solved the NaN problem.. but any idea how I can make this object fire the logout function?

Comment: @Malky.Kid sure. Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` -- setTimeout only fires once.